# My apps don't have access to my mobile internet

Tags: applications, internet

I have a very weird problem with my phone. I don't have mobile internet on any of my apps, but I can surf the internet with no problem when I am using my browser. I think it is good to mention that I am using the browser which comes with android operation system.

When I am connected to a wifi network, everything is fine. The problem is only with my mobile internet. Can someone tell me where the problem may be?

I am using HTC WildFire S. Android version of the phone is Android 2.3.5. The phone is very old and this is the final version that I can update.

Comment: Can you give an example of an app that doesn't work? What happens when you try to use Internet from this app? Is there an error message?

Comment: did u limit your data usage?

Comment: Nope it just says "Can't connect to the network" or "No internet connection". About the limit data usage, I haven't done anything to that. I would also include that I bought a tablet and I have connected the tablet and the phone on one Google account if this may be a problem. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: Not sure if it also applies to you, but some network providers may have data plans that only works on specific apps (e.g. browsing plan, WhatsApp plan, FaceBook plan). You might need to check with your provider if this is the case or not.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons

1. Check your device's date if it is set for today.
2. Try to reset your Internet settings that is access point settings
3. Make sure that you have enough memory
4. Clear catch and app data for that particular app
5. Try restarting your device two or more times
6. Make sure you have the latest updated apps

If any of the above does not work unfortunately I have to say that you need to reset your device. Let us know which one of above solution works for you

Answer (score 0):

Some phones have an option to disable Internet access to the apps in the Settings -> Apps. Check if (the app you want Internet) has Internet access in there.